# @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars complains when parameter is used only for generics

Tags: typescript, generics, eslint

In one of my functions, I have added an argument which determines the return type from that function. I use it to specify which APIs are loaded in an initializer and therefore always should have data. Simplified example:

```
interface CanBeUndefined {
  data: [] | undefined;
}

interface AlwaysHasData {
  data: [];
}

interface Query {}

const query: Query = {};
const canBeUndefined = parseQuery(query, true);
const cannotBeUndefined = parseQuery(query, false);

function parseQuery<TCouldBeUndefined extends boolean>(
  query: Query,
  couldBeUndefined: TCouldBeUndefined // This is where the error occurs
) {
  // Do stuff with query
  return query as TCouldBeUndefined extends true
    ? CanBeUndefined
    : AlwaysHasData;
}
```

My problem here is that the eslint rule @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars throws an error because of the parameter couldBeUndefined, which is technically correct. The variable is never used other than for generics.

Is there a way to solve this without disabling that rule one way or another? Is this a use-case that should maybe even be accepted by that rule?

Comment: Sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/no-unused-vars-and-generics-0jmx4l?file=/src/index.ts:0-475

Comment: I do get it. Your variables are unused in this file. Where do you wanna use them ?  Also the error will go away if you export these variables.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Well, they are kind of used - to decide what the return type should be.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler What do you mean by exporting the variables?

Comment: No `cannotBeUndefined ` is not used in your code !

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Ah... but that variable is not the one I am asking about. I ask about the parameter "couldBeUndefined" in the function parseQuery.